# ls default sorting inconsistent

Tags: ls, sort

Why does adding identical characters to the end of filenames change the sort order as shown below? In any sane string comparison method I would expect the comparison of 2 strings to not differ if the same string is added to the end of both of them.

```
$ type ls
ls is aliased to `ls --color=auto`
$ touch I II III IV V VI
$ ls
I  II  III  IV  V  VI
$ rm -f *
$ for n in I II III IV V VI; do touch "$n x"; done
$ ls 
III x  II x  IV x  I x  VI x  V x
```

Mean while Python works like I would expect:

```
>>> ns = ['I', 'II', 'III', 'IV', 'V', 'VI']
>>> sorted(ns)
['I', 'II', 'III', 'IV', 'V', 'VI']
>>> sorted(n + ' x' for n in ns)
['I x', 'II x', 'III x', 'IV x', 'V x', 'VI x']
>>>
```

Comment: Hint: `LANG=C ls` and `LANG=en_US.UTF-8 ls`

Comment: “I would expect the comparison of 2 strings to not differ if the same string is added to the end of both of them.” — No, that is not true of *any* sane string comparison. It fails in particular when one of the string is a prefix of another: `a < aa` but `ab > aab`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

as the comment from cyrus hinted, the reason is the collating rules (=locale-aware string comparison). In your case, with most non C/POSIX locales (e.g. 'en_US.UTF-8'), space characters are ignored when comparing strings, thus "Ix" and "I x" are evaluated to be equal, and as a result, "II" comes before "Ix".

See the following:

```
$ touch I "I x" "Ix" "II" IIx "II x"
```

When using a non-C locale, often spaces are ignored when comparing strings:

```
$ locale | grep LANG
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US

$ ls -lhog
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 0 Dec 26 17:12 I
-rw-rw-r-- 1 0 Dec 26 17:12 II
-rw-rw-r-- 1 0 Dec 26 17:12 IIx
-rw-rw-r-- 1 0 Dec 26 17:12 II x
-rw-rw-r-- 1 0 Dec 26 17:12 Ix
-rw-rw-r-- 1 0 Dec 26 17:12 I x
```

Forcing a POSIX/C locale, filenames are compared by ASCII characters, thus 'space' characters comes before 'x' or 'I':

```
$ LC_ALL=C ls -lhog
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 0 Dec 26 17:12 I
-rw-rw-r-- 1 0 Dec 26 17:12 I x
-rw-rw-r-- 1 0 Dec 26 17:12 II
-rw-rw-r-- 1 0 Dec 26 17:12 II x
-rw-rw-r-- 1 0 Dec 26 17:12 IIx
-rw-rw-r-- 1 0 Dec 26 17:12 Ix
```

To see the actual comparison function results (`strcoll(3)`), use `ltrace` like so:

```
$ LC_ALL=C ltrace -e strcoll ls -lhog
ls->strcoll("I", "II x")       = -73
ls->strcoll("Ix", "I")         = 120
ls->strcoll("Ix", "II x")      = 47
ls->strcoll("I x", "II")       = -41
ls->strcoll("IIx", "I x")      = 41
ls->strcoll("IIx", "II")       = 120
ls->strcoll("I x", "I")        = 32
ls->strcoll("I x", "II x")     = -41
ls->strcoll("II", "II x")      = -32
ls->strcoll("IIx", "II x")     = 88
ls->strcoll("IIx", "Ix")       = -47
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 0 Dec 26 17:12 I
-rw-rw-r-- 1 0 Dec 26 17:12 I x
-rw-rw-r-- 1 0 Dec 26 17:12 II
-rw-rw-r-- 1 0 Dec 26 17:12 II x
-rw-rw-r-- 1 0 Dec 26 17:12 IIx
-rw-rw-r-- 1 0 Dec 26 17:12 Ix
+++ exited (status 0) +++

$ LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 ltrace -e strcoll ls -lhog
ls->strcoll("I", "II x")       = -1
ls->strcoll("Ix", "I")         = 1
ls->strcoll("Ix", "II x")      = 15
ls->strcoll("I x", "II")       = 15
ls->strcoll("IIx", "II")       = 1
ls->strcoll("IIx", "I x")      = -15
ls->strcoll("II", "I")         = 1
ls->strcoll("II", "II x")      = -1
ls->strcoll("IIx", "II x")     = -1
ls->strcoll("I x", "II x")     = 15
ls->strcoll("I x", "Ix")       = 1
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 0 Dec 26 17:12 I
-rw-rw-r-- 1 0 Dec 26 17:12 II
-rw-rw-r-- 1 0 Dec 26 17:12 IIx
-rw-rw-r-- 1 0 Dec 26 17:12 II x
-rw-rw-r-- 1 0 Dec 26 17:12 Ix
-rw-rw-r-- 1 0 Dec 26 17:12 I x
+++ exited (status 0) +++
```